# Power BI using measure value as slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a table in Power BI which contains two currencies HKD and USD.

[This is the original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cywQO.png)

and I have also created measure in order to exchange the currency of HKD into USD with a fixed rate of 7.8

[This is the measure with the additional "Amount USD" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP1ce.png).

I would like to add a slicer filter with "between" sliding function to filter the transaction amount by using the values of the "Amount USD" column, however Power BI would not allow me to do so.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: This isn't possible by default as of today. Btw, There is a workaround, Check this [answer](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Cannot-use-measure-in-slicer/m-p/168236#M73486).

Comment: Create DAX calculated column or custom column in Power Query instead of a measure.